# Node.js Should Functions be Declared outside of other functions? (With express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Because Node runs the code inside a `require` call and then exports the members defined in it, it seems like it would be better to define functions outside of functions when that module is `required` or used multiple times.

For instance, take the following two codes using express:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
   function logTest () {
    console.log('log test');
   }
});
```

And

```
function logTest () {
    console.log('log test'); 
}
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
   logTest () {
});
```

It seems like the code in the second answer would be more efficient because `logTest` is only defined one time as opposed to being defined every time a get request is made.  Is this true? Are there any best practices about where to define these functions?

I have looked around [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541921/nesting-functions-in-nodejs-javascript) and not found anything that really gets to my question here.

**EDIT:**
In addition to performance gains, (for which, in Node, the answer seems to be little to none) I am interested in style / maintainability and if one technique is preferred to the other in this respect.

Thank you

Comment: yes, but it doesn't matter as much as you might think in V8, since it can recycle identical functions.

Comment: The thing is if you declare a function. The function's definition is always taken to the top. This is called hoisting. So I don't think there is any need for declaring it outside.

Comment: @binariedMe: it's taken to the top of the scope of the function that it appears in, which each function has a private version of, so they are not the same.

Comment: @dandavis "in V8, since it can recycle identical functions." --- what does it mean?

Comment: @zerkms: it means V8 doesn't have to parse the functionBody each time the server is hit. this was explicitly allowed in ecma3, not sure if the language was preserved, but the optimization when i checked a couple years ago with a memory benchmark.

Comment: @dandavis why would it parse anything for the second time if parsing is a one-time-pre-runtime step?

Comment: @zerkms: well "parse" is not the best choice of words, but my point is that identical nested functions `(String(f1)==String(f2))` need not be "made from scratch" like they would be in a naive interpreter like IE6, if executing them is provably side-effect free.

Comment: @dandavis I can hardly believe that: just because function bodies are the same does not mean they will behave the same (and that they should be compiled to the same low level bytecode). But anyway :-)

Comment: code, closures (and `this` for arrows), and arguments are all decided at different points, which is clearer in "es6" than 3 or 5 was, but even 3 mentioned internal function re-usability. when folks say a nested function is "redefined" when the outer executes, they might be over-estimating the effort needed to "redefine"...